# Hartogs' theorem in Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, analytic-functions

In complex analysis one learns Hartogs' theorem:

> Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ open and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a function. Then $f$ is analytic iff for all $1\leq i \leq n$
>   $$ z \mapsto f(z_1, \dots, z_{i-1}, z, z_{i+1}, \dots, z_n) $$
>   is analytic.

Can we generalize this theorem to the Banach space setting? I.e. does the following statement hold?

> Let $X,Y, Z$ be complex Banach spaces, $U\times V \subseteq X \times Y$ open and $f: U\times V \rightarrow Z$. Then $f$ is analytic iff $u \mapsto f(u, v_0) $ and $v\mapsto f(u_0, v)$ are analytic.

If the statement is false, what would be reasonable assumption such that the statement becomes true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is true and stated as Theorem 14.27 in the book [Holomorphy and Calculus in Normed Spaces](https://books.google.com/books?id=wtrvhCdbsd8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Soo Bong Chae. If you need even more sophisticated generalizations, you can also look at the notes related to Section 2.76 on Page 415 of [Complex Analysis in Locally Convex Spaces](https://books.google.com/books?id=4yEm92kChEoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Seán Dineen

Comment: no pbm. I just added another pointer to the literature if needed.